# Linear systems and bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, svd

Given a general linear system $Ax = y$ and the bilinear form $z(x,y) = y^T Ax$, what are the links between these two mathematical objects?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Original question is too general and difficult to answer, so let me to tell you why I posted it.

In proving SVD theorem, one starts observing that for every matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, by a compactness argument, there exist **unitary** vectors $u$ and $v$ such that:

$$Av=\sigma u$$ 
with $\sigma = ||A||_{2}$. Now:

1) May we translate this statement in terms of the above bilinear form $u^T Av$?

2) If yes, how to do it?

Thanks again.

Comment: with $<.>$ as the inner product, $z(x,y)$ just equals $<Ax,y>$

Comment: Well the best book which in my opinion is canonical is the famous book by Hirsch and Smale titled "Differential equations, dynamical systems and linear algebra"